# Running JUnit tests programmatically outside of their Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to run JUnit tests from an application that is being developed in Eclipse, like so:

```
JUnitCore junitCore = new JUnitCore();
ClassLoader cl = Main.class.getClassLoader();
Class<?> test = cl.loadClass("test.TestCase1");
Result r = junitCore.run(test);
```

This runs fine, but if the test case needs to use some files, I get a `FileNotFoundException`. Running the same test in the Eclipse project, the test has no such error. I think this is because my JVM's working directory (defined in the `user.dir` property) is not the same as the Eclipse project. As far as I know, I cannot change the `user.dir` in a running JVM.

What can I do to change this behavior? Is my only option to fire a new JVM with the same working directory as the Eclipse project? If so, how can I do that, preferably without using tools like Ant?

**edit:**
Here is an example of a test that passes in the Eclipse project, and generates a `FileNotFoundException` when I run it programmatically outside of the project:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("test1.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
    assertEquals("file content", br.readLine());
}
```

Comment: Could you show code snippest, which load your files ?

Comment: @Umar You mean an example of a test that loads a file? I will edit that in for you.

Comment: Just curious to know, why would you like to write an application to run junit, when you have junit plugin by default in eclipse ?

Comment: @SajanChandran Because my tool is also instrumenting the tested classes, so I can gather some information about them. I'm not just running JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename")));
```

If your file is in the same directory as java class it should be loaded.

**Update**

In this case, try to specify working directory when you run your JUnits tests

```
-Duser.dir=somedir
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot change the project source, including tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the current Directory your JUnit Test is in and then create a new File navigating to the test1.txt

```
String currentDirectory = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(currentDirectory+"\\XYZ\\test1.txt");
```